# Problem with destination in file upload with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files with PHP to 000webhost,but I am facing problems with the destination path.

I used this line of code

```
 $target_path = "/public_html" .$filename;
```

But thid does not work.Can someone help me how to set the destination path when uploading file to remote server?

Comment: Maybe `$target_path = "/public_html/" . $filename`?

Comment: `$target_path = $filename;` I assume the PHP code lives in `public_html`

Answer (score 0):

1. enter `000webhost's`' File Manager.
2. create folder `uploads` under `public_html`.
3. set your code like the follower: `$target_path="uploads/" . $filename;`